# Bad URI Exception While Reading Jena Model

Tags: java, rdf, jena

I am converting my input stream into a Jena Model. But apparently I get this error :

```
org.apache.jena.riot.system.ErrorHandlerFactory$ErrorLogger", Bad character in IRI (space):
```

When I checked, indeed there was a space in a URI and I know it's not valid. But is there any way or any ugly solution to do this without correcting the data.

I did found something like **reader.setProperty("allowBadURIs", "true")** but it seems that only applies to RDF Writer

Here is my code:

```java
InputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(new File(file_location);

Model modelResult = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel().read(rdfInput, "", "RDF/XML");
```

URL Example

```
"http://openfashion.momu.be/9f spelden en verpakkingen momu fs "
```

Comment: From Jena's history, we know that spaces cause other problems, lots of questions and unusable (corrupted) databases. It is a tradeoff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there isn't a way. The data has a broken token and good recovery is hard. There two problems with allowing spaces through:

Sometimes the data is broken so it is not a space in a URI, it is a missing terminating ">" (the error is from the tokenizer processing characters on input)
from earlier so a large amount of text might be read as one URI.

Once ingested, such bad IRIs a cause downstream problems (e.g.they aren't reliably printable).  Only some writers can cope and then they output RDF other systems can't read.

The solution is to fix the input so as not to defer the problems that will arise later, especially if stored in a persistent database.

Comment: I think fixing the data is the best option. Thank you

Comment: Actually, jena is able to write such uris (out of the box) but not to read which is inconsitent. I would either read/write it or forbid it especially if you are writing a models as a backup method which are not readable later on. Eg DFDataMgr.write writes uris containing spaces with no problem (NQUADS). I know this because I am facting the exact problem.